# Modelform ForeignKey - How to avoid HTML select auto-population?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a `Person` model which have a relationship with a `City` model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATES)
    city = models.ForeignKey('City')

class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Person

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

I am using a `ModelForm` to render the Person form in the template, through the `as_p` attribute.

I have a pre-loaded set of data for the `City` database (it is a huge set of data in the DB), and I don't wan't that data to be loaded into a `select` list in the form created to include `Person`.

Is there any way to avoid that set of data being loaded in the html, using `ModelForm` and the `as_p` attribute?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse, you can overwrite any field or any widget, have a look, the django documentation is pretty clear on this:

[modelform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets)